# import table.frm, table.myd and table.myi

Tags: mysql, import

I have a couple of tables, each has 3 files .frm .myi and .myd, and I want to import them directly to MySQL Server 8.
With XAMPP MySQL I only do Copy/Paste in Data/ folder, I restart and I have my DB.

Why this does not apply for MySQL Server 8.0?

Comment: And what version of MySQL are these files coming from?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960845/mysql-backup-can-i-copying-individual-myisam-table-files-to-another-server-with

Comment: I am fairly sure that simply copying myisam file was only ever recommended if you were moving the data between the same or at least very similiar version of MySQL. MYSQL8 is quite a big change from previous versions so this method is unlikely to work if your data is coming from a pre mysql8 version

Comment: @RiggsFolly, copying MyISAM files around was never recommended.

Comment: @BillKarwin Point taken, my comment was obviously badly phrased, although it was possible under the conditions I mentioned

Answer (score 1):

MySQL 8.0 changed the way they store table metadata. [They don't use .frm files anymore.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-dictionary-file-removal.html)

This means you can't just copy data and metadata files around to import a table.

To import a table, you need an .sql file, like the one produced by `mysqldump`.

This is a good opportunity to import the data into InnoDB tables. It's not a good idea to use MyISAM tables.

Comment: You can transport table spaces -- see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/tablespace-copying.html

Comment: @DaveStokes, The OP said they have a MYD, MYI, and FRM file — in other words, a MyISAM table. Transportable tablespaces only work if one has a file-per-table InnoDB tablespaces that has been exported.